# How can i execute my django custom command with cron in a python script

Tags: django, cron

I have created a Django custom command. I would like to run this command at specific inervals of time (say for example every 5 minutes). How can i make this from my script or from terminal.

My django custom command in periodic_tasks.py:

`class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Displays Data....'

```
def handle(self, *args, **options):
        hostip = '192.168.1.1'
        cmd = 'sudo nmap -sV -T4 -O -F --version-light -oX - '+hostip
        scandate = timezone.now()
        #scandate = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.addToLog('Detailed Scan',hostip,scandate,'Started')
        child = pexpect.spawn(cmd, timeout = 60)
        index = child.expect (['password:',pexpect.EOF, pexpect.TIMEOUT])
        child.sendline('abcdef')
        scandate = timezone.now()
        self.addToLog('Detailed Scan',hostip,scandate,'Finished')
        print 'before xml.....'
        with open('portscan.xml', 'w') as fObj:
            fObj.write(child.before)
            print 'in xml.....'
        print 'after xml.....'
        portscandata = self.parsexml()
        self.addToDB(portscandata,hostip)`
```

In my script I am trying to do this:

`test = subprocess.Popen(["*/5","*","*","*", "*", "/usr/local/bin/python2.6","periodic_tasks"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = test.communicate()[0]`

I am trying to run this from terminal like this:

`*/5 * * * * root /usr/local/bin/python2.6 /home/sat034/WorkSpace/SAFEACCESS/NetworkInventory/manage.py periodic_tasks`

It is saying:
bash: */5: No such file or directory

Please suggest me if I am missing somewhere. Thanks in Advance

Comment: You need to install this cron job in the crontab. You can't execute it in command line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string

```
*/5 * * * * root /usr/local/bin/python2.6 /home/sat034/WorkSpace/SAFEACCESS/SynfosysNetworkInventory/manage.py periodic_tasks
```

looks like cron configuration string. You can add it to cron with crontab -e (editor will be started so you will add this line)

Meaning of this line is "run every 5 minutes next command"

before adding to cron i suggest test this command running it without */5 * * * *

Comment: Sure also without "root":

/usr/local/bin/python2.6 /home/sat034/WorkSpace/SAFEACCESS/SynfosysNetworkInventory/manage.py periodic_tasks